# ECR lifecycle policies to remove untagged images and keep the latest 150 tagged images

Tags: amazon-ecr

I have below lifecycle policies defined for my ECR repos to remove untagged images and keep the latest 150 tagged images.

```
{
  "rules": [
    {
      "rulePriority": 2,
      "description": "Keep last 150 images",
      "selection": {
        "tagStatus": "any",
        "countType": "imageCountMoreThan",
        "countNumber": 150
      },
      "action": {
        "type": "expire"
      }
    },
    {
      "rulePriority": 1,
      "description": "Remove untagged images",
      "selection": {
        "tagStatus": "untagged",
        "countType": "imageCountMoreThan",
        "countNumber": 1
      },
      "action": {
        "type": "expire"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But above lifecycle policies do not work as expected. The policy to remove untagged image seems not working at all. PolicyExecutionEvent has been showing no image effected since the policies were created.
[image]

However, when i run test rules, it can match the untagged image as expected（338 untagged images were matched）. Is it an issue with AWS ECR or there is something wrong with my lifecycle policies.
[image]

I tried to reapply the test rules and changed the policy of removing untagged images. But it was not working

Comment: Do you have your rules set in "test area" only? My guess is you didn't apply them as a lifecycle policy.

Comment: Hi @michail_w I applied them. The rules are created by cli `aws ecr put-lifecycle-policy ...`.  i found it has been not working since it was created. Then i copied the rules to test from aws ecr console.

Comment: I believe this is a bug in AWS. I have the exact same rule in place, and testing shows many images should match, but events history shows nothing is being removed.

Comment: Follow up: I reviewed PolicyExecutionEvents in CloudTrail and found that the lifecycle policy is running, but the images I expected it to delete were referenced by tagged image manifests. So, for my situation at least, things are working as they should.

Comment: Hi @JR. I checked the PolicyExecutionEvent, and found it was the same situation for my case. The untagged imaged is referenced by other image manifests. Thanks！